# Creating a window with Windows.Forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, csc

I am creating windows using Method1

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    static class Program {
        public static void Main(){
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    class Form1:Form 
    {

    public Form1(){
    
        }
    }
```

Method 2

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    static class Program {
        public static void Main(){
        Form frm=new Form();
        Application.Run(frm);
        }
    }
```

Which is appropriate while writing c# code. Differentiate both please.

Answer (score 2):

For your case, certainly the first one (though it doesn't matter much), but without the inheritance.

Inheritance should be used if you wanted to extend the `Form` object to contain more properties and or methods.

```
static class Program {
        public static void Main(){
        Application.Run(new Form());
        }
    }
```

But what happens here:

```
Form frm=new Form();
Application.Run(frm);
```

You are creating a reference to your `Form` object. This is not needed, as you are doing nothing with it.

What could you do with it?

Check the methods and properties section in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=netcore-3.1#methods

Comment: Both lines of code create same window form. In Second method no need to define class Form1.

Comment: There is no need for `Form1` in either case. Especially since you don't extend it really with anything.